# Should the Generic be BaseInputProps?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface Params<P = BaseInputProps> {
  renderer: React.ComponentType<P>
}


<FieldComponent {...mergedProps} />
```

mergedProps is a BaseInputProps Type

I expected  should be React.ComponentType If I didn't pass any generic to current Class.

But TypeScript inferred  is React.ComponentType

I don't know why, could someone help?

My TypeScript version is 3.2.4

Comment: I switch my Typescript to 2.9.X version.
It works... Does someone know the reason?